# Mobile Tab Navigation

Tags: css, materialize

I would like to achieve a mobile menu which is always visible on the bottom of my page. I don't know if there is a specific name for such menus but I've found a page which does exactly this menu:
[image]

What is the best way to achieve exactly this for tablet and smaller devices using materialize?

Comment: To improve the Quality of this Question, please give more of an indication of the research that you have performed, including links to any resources of particular interest to the matter at hand.  Please describe what you have attempted so far (including code samples), the full text of any errors that you have received.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information.

Comment: @toonice I hoped that I have missed something in the materialize framework and it looks like I did (see gwesseling's answer)

Comment: All's well that ends  well.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something called a Toolbar in Materialize.

```
  <div class="fixed-action-btn toolbar">
    <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
      <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">format_quote</i></a></li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
      <li class="waves-effect waves-light"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

But it's not the same what you are looking for. You have to modify this or you need to create your own.

Fab for toolbar:
http://materializecss.com/buttons.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use CSS, select the whole menu by class or id and set it to position fixed?

```
#fixedMenu{
  position:fixed;
  }
```

You can then play around as the where exactly you want to place it. By using width or margins set to auto then you can make it responsive for different viewports.